# Failed to Launching Emulator React native run-android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

Why this error occurs, can anyone help me to solve it please?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots on stack overflow. It is highly frowned upon here.

Comment: Did you setup the environment as the documentation says?

Comment: Thanks for the advice @developer01

Comment: Yes I did @KianaKazeminejad, following setup according to the documentation it says, like a set SDK manager, set Environment Variable and more. But i have 2 emulators on AVD, one is android 11 and one is android 5